# history.stackexchange.com keeping connection open

Tags: bug

Recently I notice history.stackexchange.com has been keeping the connection open, i.e., the browser is constantly receiving information, which is very rude behavior for a web site because it steals CPU cycles from the client machine. This is sometimes called "hanging the browser". Has something changed in how the site is programmed?

Other Stack Exchange sites do not exhibit the same behavior and close the connection after the page is loaded, which is the proper thing to do; so, this seems to be unique to History.

I have checked the main source page and it is fine. It appears to be some secondary script that gets loaded after the main page.

Also, I notice if I experiment with my settings I get the following warning:

[image: xss warning]

which would seem to indicate that the site is using foreign javascript. I am not an expert in cross-site scripting vulnerabilities, but my understanding is that is not secure to be doing that.

Comment: I've seen other sites hang my browser, but never SE sites. I think the amount of information passed back and forth is minimal, just enough so it can do in page alerts (two new questions; click to load).

Answer (score 1):

The second half (starting with "also") [is addressed here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188125/dreaded-error-stack-overflow-requires-external-javascript-from-another-domain).

The first half I don't know much of anything about. AFAIK the software used on this stack is no different than used on all the other stacks. It probably even shares physical servers with some of them. So I wouldn't expect you to see any great behavioral differences.

I do happen to know a bit about that behavior in theory (I've written my share of web servers). But I'd need way more information to do any proper debugging and *I don't have access to the stack's hardware or software to do anything about what I'd find*. HTTP is a many layered thing. There are even some situations where modern web servers and browsers will, by mutual consent, reuse connections.